# как из строки сделать столбик скриптом Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
Есть строка:
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
192.168.0.2:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
192.168.0.3:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
и т.д до 1млн строк

Нужно:
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто `split` использовать несколько раз:

```
data = \
'''192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
192.168.0.2:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
192.168.0.3:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов'''

for line in data.split('\n'):
    ip, rest = line.split('-', 1)
    for name in rest.split(';'):
        print(f'{ip}-{name}')
```

Вывод:

```
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов
192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
192.168.0.2:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов
192.168.0.2:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов
192.168.0.2:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов
192.168.0.2:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
192.168.0.3:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов
192.168.0.3:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов
192.168.0.3:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов
192.168.0.3:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов
```

Comment: CrazyElf выражаю огромную Благодарность, работает идеально. Пошел искать как бы python забирал файл с исходными строками (192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;) а после преобразования сохранял результат в файл. Знаний ЯП -0- .

Answer (score 0):

```py
txt = '192.168.0.1:80-Бухгалтерия\Иван Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван_Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван.Иванов;Бухгалтерия\Иван-Иванов'
txt = txt.split(';');
txt[0] = txt[0][len('192.168.0.1:80-'):]
print(txt)
for i in txt:
    print('192.168.0.1:80-'+i)
```